# "LookupError: unknown encoding: ascii" when running bootstrap

Tags: python, macos, encoding, buildout

I'm using zc.buildout, and when I try to run bootstrap (for the first time on a new computer), I'm receiving the following error below:

```
>> python2.7 bootstrap.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 158, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/../../Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 698, in <module>
    class Environment(object):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/../../Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 701, in Environment
    def __init__(self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(), python=PY_MAJOR):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/../../Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 99, in get_supported_platform
    plat = 'macosx-%s-%s' % ('.'.join(_macosx_vers()[:2]), m.group(3))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/../../Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 209, in _macosx_vers
    _cache.append(mac_ver()[0].split('.'))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 803, in mac_ver
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 780, in _mac_ver_xml
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 78, in readPlist
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 406, in parse
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 418, in handleEndElement
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 452, in end_key
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 436, in getData
LookupError: unknown encoding: ascii
```

Has anyone seen this before or know how to fix it? It appears to have something to do with getting the current version of my operating system. My operating system is Mac 10.8.2.

Thanks!

Comment: @dbr I only encountered bootstrap.py when working with [zc.buildout](http://svn.zope.org/*checkout*/zc.buildout/trunk/bootstrap/bootstrap.py) - but it never exploded like this for me. It seems to be a problem with python installation, not with `bootstrap.py` anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I updated my question to clarify that I'm working with zc.buildout.

Answer (score 3):

As Vitaly answered, the problem is indeed that the original .py files are missing in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/` (there are only .pyc files there in a clean installation). Specifically, these files have to exist for bootstrap.py to succeed:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py
```

You can copy them from a virtualenv or from a different computer.

Comment: If it's helpful, I was able to fix this issue by downloading the latest Python 2.7 release source code and then copying the two files needed. After that, everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

Check if `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7` contains uncompilled modules (*.py). They are missing by default and here is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the Xcode Command Line Tools solved the problem for me, although I can't explain why. You can install these from Xcode under

```
Preferences -> Downloads
```

or from the [Apple Developers download page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a Mountain Lion only problem, and only if your python was installed fresh on it (or so the reports seem to indicate).

The work-around is to run python with the `-S` switch:

```
python2.7 -S bootstrap.py
```

or to create a virtualenv, then run the `bootstrap.py` script with the virtualenv python.