# How to resolve error in python - LookupError: unknown encoding: us-ascii

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a simple `.xlsx` excel file with no data. I want to write a value to a cell and save the workbook.

When I try using this code in Python 3.11.4:

```
import openpyxl
path = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\Integration_Recon\\Output\\file.xlsx"
target_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
target_sheet = target_workbook['Sheet1']
target_sheet.cell(row=2, column=2, value = "111111")
target_workbook.save(path)
```

I get an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\abc\Downloads\Integration_Recon\Code\tst2.py", line 6, in <module>
    target_workbook.save(path)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 386, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 294, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 77, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 215, in _write_worksheets
    self.write_worksheet(ws)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 200, in write_worksheet
    writer.write()
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 361, in write
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 369, in close
    self.xf.close()
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 289, in get_stream
    with xf.element("worksheet", xmlns=SHEET_MAIN_NS):
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 144, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line 50, in element
    self._write_element(el)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line 77, in _write_element
    xml = tostring(element)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1098, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(stream, encoding,
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 731, in write
    with _get_writer(file_or_filename, encoding) as (write, declared_encoding):
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 794, in _get_writer
    file = io.TextIOWrapper(file,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
LookupError: unknown encoding: us-ascii
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?
I've tried looking through online links but couldn't figure out the issue. May be I can try through pandas but I have a large part of code written in openpyxl so dont want to try other module.

Comment: The problem is probably occurring with `load_workbook()` function. Can you, please, provide a full stacktrace? The answer you might be interested in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447032/lookuperror-unknown-encoding-ascii-when-running-bootstrap

Comment: Your traceback does not match your code. Please update the question with the real traceback.

Comment: Hi Klaus. Thanks for your response! Apologies. 
Updated traceback.

Comment: That's a really weird error; there is definitely an encoding called `"us-ascii"` and very few things would work if it wasn't included in Python.

Comment: I just tried to run the same code in some other machine and it worked fine. Looks like there's a python installation issue in my system. Will try and get it reinstalled.